# Nuxt Apollo SSR query that depends on another query's result

Tags: vue.js, graphql, apollo, server-side-rendering, nuxt.js

Similar questions in SO are not SSR (Server Side Rendering) specific and their answers do not apply in my case.

I'm using [@nuxtjs/apollo](https://github.com/nuxt-community/apollo-module) which is based on [vue-cli-plugin-apollo](https://github.com/Akryum/vue-cli-plugin-apollo) and [vue-apollo](https://github.com/Akryum/vue-apollo)

I have two queries `X` and `Y`. A variable of `Y` is taken from result of `X`. I want to execute both queries on **server side**. How to achieve that?

Simplified example below is closest I can get. However query `Y` is executed at **client side**.

```js
{
  apollo: {
    X: {
      query: X
    },
    Y: {
      query: Y,
      variables() {
        return { id: this.X.someField };
      },
      skip() {
        return !this.X; // Skip until X have some result.
      }
    },
  }
}
```

Basically I want:

- Execute query X on server and get result.
- Execute query Y on server with a variable from result of query X.

Many thanks,

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and finally found a solution after trying many options.
Query `X` and `Y` can be run sequentially on **server-side** by using parent and child Vue components.

1. Run query `X` in the parent component.
2. Pass the result of `X` to the child component via props.
3. Run query `Y` in the child component with variables from props.

Comment: I also found that urql (another graphql client library) can handle multiple sequential query on SSR. I'm thinking to move to urql from apollo because of this feature.
https://formidable.com/open-source/urql/docs/basics/vue/#chaining-calls-in-vue-suspense

Answer (score 1):

As per @y15e's answer, it works to run the dependent query in a child component using the result passed from the parent via a prop, as long as you handle the state before X exists. Just using a computed property and a ternary to pass an empty string worked for me.

In the parent...

```
{
  apollo: {
    X: {
      query: X
    }
  }
}
```

Child component

```
{
  props: ['X'],
  computed: {
    Xvalue: function() {
      return (this.X ? this.X : '');
    }
  },
  apollo: {
    Y: {
      query: Y,
      variables() {
        return { id: this.Xvalue };
      },
      skip() {
        return !this.Xvalue;
      }
    },
  }
}
```

Comment: I initially thought this worked but it leads to a mismatch between server and client. These were hard to debug as no errors are thrown in dev and it initially appears to work on the client but in certain cases it crashed the app in live. So the asyncData options from the parent page rather than the component seems like the only way.

Answer (score 0):

Normally when you have a query that depends on the result of another query, you utilize the `skip` option to prevent requesting the second query until the first query resolves. However, [skipping the query means it won't be prefetched](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-apollo/blob/0051c43f572f83270ed2de92516d564708a50728/packages/vue-apollo/src/mixin.js#L96). I think the only way you can do what you're trying to do is to utilize `asyncData` instead of relying on smart queries -- you'd have to call the `query` method directly on an instance of ApolloClient. You *might* be able to do that just for the first query and then use the resulting data as a variable value in your second query but off-hand, I don't know if `asyncData` is fetched before your queries are prefetched.

As an aside, if you are querying against your own server, you might consider updating your API. Typically cases where you need to have two queries chained like this are indicative of poor schema design. For example, I shouldn't have to fetch a user, get their ID and then fetch the user's posts by the ID -- I should be able to fetch the entire graph of data in one query (the user and their posts).

Comment: Thanks Daniel for the answer. API is not under my control. I want to find a way to stick with smart queries, because I don't want to lose smart query features using asyncData.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't believe there's any way to do what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

I am running into the same issue.
The reason why it happens because there is no reactive in SSR. but the whole apollo client composition APIs are designed in reactive way.
that what it works.

to deal with this, we can get the apollo client and query the result in async way, so that we can await the result in SSR.

```
    const apolloClient = useApolloClient()
    const result = await apolloClient.client.query({
      query: QueryDocument,
    })
```

or await the result before the second query execute.

```
await until(firstQueryResult).toBeTruthy()
```